# Rename exported typescript enum in VSCode: how do you propagate name in modules that uses it?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When renaming an exported with "Rename" in VSCode, it doesn't propagate. Is there a way ?

I don't have "Rename Symbol" for EXPORTED module that's the point.

Comment: I don't see a "Rename" option when I right click a variable name but there's a "Rename Symbol" option that should do what you want.

Comment: @YulricSequeira I don't have "Rename Symmbol" for EXPORTED module that's the point.